# Reacting to changes to a Python defined RNA Property

Tags: python

Hey I have a questions

I have a prop_search which is filled with names. Is there some kind of callback when I change the selection of the prop_search?
like I have this:

```
def draw(self, context):
    col = layout.column()        
    col.prop_search(context.scene, "hdri", context.scene, "coll", icon='OBJECT_DATA')
```

can I somehow define a function that is triggered whenever I change the prop_search?

---

*I'm pretty new to Python for Blender.*

Comment: alright, I deleted the second question :)

Comment: Domi do you understand the new title to this question? (what an RNA property is)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, for any property, you can define a `set` and `update` callbacks.

These are functions you define, passed as an argument and called by Blender whenever the property changes.

- `get` - you can return the value and store it wherever you like.
- `set` - you're responsible for making sure the new value is stored/modified.
- `update` - is called after setting, often used to ensure related data is updated.

See: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty

---

In the example above, you would have to set the callback on the `hdri` property definition.

Comment: thanks, but I'm confused, how can I set an update-function for my example above?

Comment: @Domi, updated answer.

Comment: @Domi: you can't define a callback in UI code (panel / prop_search). It must be specified for the property when it is set up.